# Multiple color background HTML

Tags: html, css, gradient

I'm trying to create a multiple color background to implement this:

And right now I managed to do this:

What I did:

[image: What I did]

Desired Background:

[image: Desired Background]

I'm trying to do it using gradients, but it seems that it's not possible to combine two gradients to do that. (It's possible to do other things, but not this).

Is there a way to implement this backgorund?

Thanks!

Comment: add your code too please?

Comment: Do you mean the gray background where the place and time is plus the arrow?

Comment: Thanks Pauli for your comment. It really help me!! I never even thought of searching Google, what a stupid developer I am.

Comment: I end up using a gradient for the green colour and I used this for the gray color: .assignment-item:before{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  bottom:0;
  left:2%;
  width:100%;
  height:25%;
  content:"";
  background-color:#f2f2f2;
}

Answer (score 2):

Try this (adjust the percentage and colors as your needs):

```
.yourdiv{
background: #ffffff;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%, #ffffff 70%, #f1f1f1 70%, #f1f1f1 100%);
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #ffffff 0%,#ffffff 70%,#f1f1f1 70%,#f1f1f1 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #ffffff 0%,#ffffff 70%,#f1f1f1 70%,#f1f1f1 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#f1f1f1',GradientType=0 );

}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/luispa/kd4kjdck/180/)**

Answer (score 0):

i am guessing u need the darker grey section in the desired output to be shown?  if so i would suggest to divide it into sections and give individual background. 
if u can post some code. i would be happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I managed to do it with this:

This for the GREEN part:

```
.assignment-item {
  padding: 5px 5px 0px 10px !important;
  margin:15px auto;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right,  #4f8b2b 0%,#4f8b2b 2%,#ffffff 2%,#ffffff 100%, transparent) !important;
}
```

This for the GREY part:

```
.assignment-item:before{
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  bottom:0;
  left:2%;
  width:100%;
  height:25%;
  content:"";
  background-color:#f2f2f2;
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, not sure if this is exactly what you want but this is how I'd do psd to css/html. See screen shot below.[image: Screen Shot]

Also a **[WORKING DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Godinall/yxcwma0g/)**

Just wrap the whole card in a div and apply a left border would do the trick.

```
  border-left-width: 8px;
  border-left-color: rgba(10, 255, 80, 0.75);
  border-radius: 5px;
```

You may remove the box shadow if you don't want, just feel move active with it.

Comment: Thanks for the help Godinall, but as I commented yesterday, I managed to find a way to do what I need using first a ".assignment-item:before{" and then the gradient. You can see the output in the comment.

Comment: @CarlosRoig yes you can do it that way, but my method would allow you to have content of different heights in each card and still looks nice, you can play around